# What style of kung fu forms begin with legs straight, a fist in a fully extended sidepunch, and the other hand in an open palm by the shoulder?

Tags: kung-fu, forms, identification

I recall learning a bit of kung fu as a kid, and each of the forms starting with an introductory motion with at least one hand making a circle and the body ending up at something like this:

[image]

This is from an online modeling app that I found, but it lacked certain features to get it totally right.

- The fist should be turned sideways.
- The palm should face the direction of the fist.
- The head should face the direction of the fist.
- Legs and feet together, standing straight.

It's possible I'm misremembering some details.

Does anyone know what style of kung fu forms these were?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given how common Tan Tui drills are, that's probably what you were doing. It's from the Long Fist (chang quan) lineage:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fict-rt_a1I

Tan Tui sets are used to teach basic footwork, stances, and strikes. It's given to beginner students usually before moving on to full forms. There are typically 12 of these that are performed, with movement usually on a straight line across the floor. You'll see these sets in styles founded on the Jing Wu curriculum. You'll see it in Chang Quan. I learned it while studying Mi Tsung Lo Han kung-fu.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yup, that was exactly it!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

My first reaction is [long fist (*chang quan*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changquan), which is generally taught first in modern wushu. This position is not exclusive, however, so there are other possibilities as well.

Comment: _Wushu_, that was actually what it was called even, I couldn't remember. Thanks.